# What is the correct syntax to using on click within echo with an img tag?

Tags: php

I am trying to put on click in echo, but it is not working. It shows the image, but when the `onclick` is selected, it does nothing.

```
<?
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<img src ="'.$row["img"].'"'.'alt="pic" height="200px" width="250px" align = left onclick="clickedButton()" />';
    }
} 
else {
    echo "no  pic  upload ";
}
?>


<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function clickedButton()
{
    window.location = 'index.php';
}
</script>
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean, exactly? Have you checked for errors in the browser console? Where is this "clickedButton" function defined?

Comment: What does the rendered code look like? View Source, look at image tag...

Comment: Can you add more working code? Also, add details to your question, this is not a javascript question, but rather a PHP only question.

Comment: You are missing quotes around align = left

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative Way**

Create a class name, use that class name in `<script></script>`. It will work.

```
<?
.
echo '<img src ="'.$row["img"].'" class="ClassName" alt="pic" height="200px" width="250px" align = "left" />';
.
?>
```

**JS**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ClassName").click(function(){
         window.location = 'index.php';
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe it's because you have double quotes in simple quotes (it happened to me once) try adding a backslash in font of the double quotes: `\"`.

But don't do it for `$row["img"]`.